# Language Translator api in iphone

Tags: iphone, translation, google-translate

As Google Translate API is now paid i found [MSTranslateVendor](https://github.com/bitmapdata/MSTranslateVendor) Example as reference.Now as i run this code and create API key and app id it will translate my text but after some time aprox 10 min it's translate functionality will stop. [As i do some r & d for translator,at all most i found this example link as reference]

Now while i create new App Id and key and run application it will works fine but after some time same problem arrives.Please let me know some use full solution or reference to Translate text.

Comment: I'm actually running into this same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Zenox : see my answer,I create web-service which will used free Google translator API and threw that i will done this and now my app is live on itunes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this Translation you have Two Options

1) You have to register your application and purchase the key (for Google Translate API)

2) Used any Web-service which will translate your word in particular Language and then show their response

I used second option,I create PHP Web-service for translating my word.
Here you may found use full blog for that
[usage-google-translator-api-free](https://webkul.com/blog/usage-google-translator-api-free/)

Answer (score 0):

After you register with either Google or Bing translate, use [FGTranslator](https://github.com/gpolak/FGTranslator) to do the heavy lifting for you.